# Salesforce CPQ: Block Pricing with Configuration Attribute

Tags: apex, lightning, configuration, cpq

Block pricing is very useful to set the price based on the quantity of the product.
But can it be used with a configuration attribute?.

For ex:

Block Pricing

- 0-99  - $1000
- 100-199 - $2000
- 200-299 - $3000
- 300-unlimited - $5000

I have configuration attribute with values 50, 100, 200, 300, Unlimited as picklist.

Now, when we select 50, the price should be $1000 based on block pricing set up.

Any suggestions?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this use case.

I just need to set the API name of the field in "Block Pricing field" in the Product record. The API name must match with the field in the Quote Line and the same must be in the Target Field of Configuration attribute as well.